# Adding output messages to deploy hooks

Tags: engineyard

I'd like to add some messages to a deploy/before_bundle.rb hook in order to output extra details of the progress to the command-line when deploying. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
run "echo 'this will make it to the terminal'"
```

I'm just guessing that might work.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Ruby so `puts` is fine

```
puts "About to run a command"
run! "/bin/some/command"
puts "Finished"

# Sometimes the order seems off so try
$stderr.puts "About to run a command"
$stderr.flush
```

Comment: in my case `$stderr.puts "About to run a command"` worked however the `puts "About to run a command"` seems to be failing